# Knex: How to write ARRAY_AGG in having clause in knex?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I want to write this query in `knex`.

The query fetches all the student ids from the `students_subject` (joint table from `students` and `subjects`) who are enrolled to all these subject ids `['123', '456', '789']` compulsorily.

**PSQL:**

```
    select student_id from students_subject
    group by id
    having ARRAY_AGG(subject_id) @> array[
      '123'::uuid, 
      '456'::uuid, 
      '789'::uuid
    ];
```

I tried this in `knex` something like this where `subject_ids` is an `array` of `subject ids`.  The `queryBuilder` is `knex` instance passed to this function which will be returned.

**Javascript function:**  (returns the knex query)

```
    const knex = require('../../../db/knex');

    const getSudents = function( queryBuilder, subject_ids) {
      return queryBuilder.innerJoin('students_subject',
          'students_subject.student_id',
          'students.id')
        .groupBy('students_subject.student_id')
        .having(knex.raw('ARRAY_AGG(students_subject.subject_id) @> UNNEST(ARRAY[?]::uuid[])', [subject_ids]));
    }

    module.exports = getSudents;
```

1. `queryBuilder` which is passed has other logics behind and I am not allowed to modify it. My job is to build the `query` to get the student `ids` and pass.
2. The error I am getting is:

> error: set-returning functions are not allowed in HAVING

Can you help me to write the correct `knex` query?

Answer (score 0):

Knex cannot know for various reasons how to flatten javascript array to a query. So you need to flatten it manually:

```
...UNNEST(ARRAY[${subject_ids.map(() => '?').join(',')}]::uuid[])`, subject_ids));
```